# NextJS won’t show page on empty slug

Tags: next.js, graphql, strapi

I'm facing a problem with my nextJS site connected to strapi.
I've based my website on the NextJS corporate site starter.

The problem I'm having is that I can't get a page with slug "" to render, it automatically throw a 404. Someone has told me that NextJS isn't able to render page with a slug set to "", but when I look at https://strapi-starter-next-corporate.vercel.app/, it works...

Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't get a page with slug "" to render"? What is the route of the page you're trying to render?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm talking about a blank slug